# Draw A Double Arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

My Latex code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(0,4);
\draw (0.5,0)--(0.5,4);
\draw(-0.5,1.5)--(0.25,2);
\draw(0.25,2)--(1,1.5);
\draw(1.5,1.6)--(2.5,1.6);
\draw(1.5,1.9)--(2.5,1.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works well. The result is like that:

[image: propagator]

How can I draw this picture using double arrow?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Do you really need `tikz` for that? Perhaps there is something in the comprehensive symbol list: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: I need a large double arrow. I want to plot this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/myo34xj3joal327/pro2.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The resolution on your dropbox image is a little low, but I think that you are trying to make something like this:

[image]

If this is what you want then you can get it using the `double` option to the `\draw` command. This draws "double lines" rather than single lines. You can control the distance between the lines using `double distance`. Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(0,4);
\draw (0.5,0)--(0.5,4);
\draw[double,double distance=1mm](-0.5,1.5)--(0.25,2)--(1,1.5);
\draw(1.5,1.6)--(2.5,1.6);
\draw(1.5,1.9)--(2.5,1.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I also combined your two `\draw` commands for the left and right hand side of the "arrow" into one command because `\draw` accepts a series of coordinates.